# In views tests, when to use before(:all)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails

I'm writing some views tests in an application and my tests expects something like:

```
describe 'form' do
  it 'has a search form' do
    render
    expect(rendered).to have_selector 'form[id=mock_search]'
  end
  it 'has a name filter' do
    render
    expect(rendered).to have_selector 'label[for=q_name_cont]', text: 'Nome do simulado'
    expect(rendered).to have_selector 'input[id=q_name_cont]'
  end
  it 'has a submit button' do
    render
    expect(rendered).to have_selector 'input[type=submit][value="Buscar"][name=commit]'
  end
  it 'has a reset button' do
    render
    expect(rendered).to have_selector 'input[type=submit][value="Limpar filtros"]'
  end
end
```

But I have and before(:each) that iterates too many requests on application making my tests spend 25 seconds to run. I've changed to before(:all) and then become to 4 seconds.

- Should I still use before(:each)?
- Why before(:all) were not recommended?

**EDIT:** My before iterations:

```
before(:each) do
  @school = build(:school)
  @teacher = build(:teacher)
  build_list(:mock_with_proccessed_statistics, 2, school: @school, teacher: @teacher)
  @mocks = Mock.page(nil)
  @q = Mock.ransack
  allow(view).to receive(:current_school).and_return(@school)
  allow(view).to receive(:format_date) { |date, format| date.strftime(format) }
end
```

Comment: I see you're running 4 separate tests on exactly the same view. Why not just make it one test? (side note: don't test views, it's pure evil)

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I need to, I tried to fight against it but nothing is perfect :/. I just separated into many tests to have a nice documentation later. Should I just ignore it?

Comment: I personally never understood and will never understand running multiple tests on the same object (be it view or model instance) when the setup cost is high. I would make it one test and make sure to run the expensive  operation once before those tests.

Comment: The big thing here is: when I use `before(:all)` the setup runs only before describes and contexts. And this avoids completely the high cost. But theorically it can break Test Unit concepts.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what test unit concepts are that you're referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
describe 'form' do
  # 
  #let! will create create instance variable school 
  #inside your test case and assign your school build. Different between 
  #let! and let is: let! create before every task. You won't need it to put 
  #on before block and let doesn't do that you have to call it explicitly to 
  #create that mock and get values..   
  let!(:school) { build(:school) }
  let!(:teacher) { build(:teacher) }
  let!(:statistics) { build_list(:mock_with_proccessed_statistics, 2, school: @school, teacher: @teacher) }
  let!(:mocks) { Mock.page(nil) }

  subject { render }

  it 'has a search form' do
    expect{ subject }.to have_selector 'form[id=mock_search]'
  end

  it 'has a name filter' do
    expect{ subject }.to have_selector 'label[for=q_name_cont]', text: 'Nome do simulado'
    expect{ subject }.to have_selector 'input[id=q_name_cont]'
  end
end
```

Comment: I've added my before(:each).

Comment: You don't need before here at all. Let me improvise my answer.

Comment: checkout my answer. its based on your given context. You just need to tweak according to yours. Yes calling before(:each) every time might break your unit testing agility.

Answer (score 0):

`before(:each)` execute before each test case executes. and `before(:all)` once before all test cases inside a current context.

Comment: I know it, and this is exactly the behaviour I want. But when I've added it to my tests I get blamed in code review by everybody saying that `before(:each)` is not recommended cause it break Unit Tests rules avoiding mocking methods every iteration.

Comment: when working with common behaviour you can use before(:all) above all context. Try to avoid before(:each). You can do the following as well. Let me write another answer.

Comment: Just to correct my typo: `before(:all)` is not recommended.

Comment: before and before(:each) is same. you can use let! to avoid before(:each). Check my second answer.

Comment: you can also avoid before all by using let! on the first describe block! but before(:all) can only be used for any separate concerns like indexing, reindexing like task requires. Say you need to create index every time before all the task getting run.

Comment: But the behaviour of `let!` is the same of `before(:each)`, right? All the setup that I'm doing is needed to render the view properly. I don't need to have different objects every time the views is rendered. Because of this I consider using `before(:all)`. But when I do it, my coworkers are saying that I'm breaking Unit Tests rules and concepts. But I can see that.

Comment: yes I also added that in my last answer. checkout how to render view correctly and according to most accepted way.

Comment: Nice, I'll try that! Thank you!